# Private class wants variables, I want to put them in the constuctor instead

Tags: constructor, private

So I have this private method `Complex` within a class called `Generator.` It wants 6 variables as you can see below. The thing is these variables, at least `width` and `height` should come from another class called `GUI`. But it just feels weird, I dont know how to get the `width` from the `GUI` class into my `Complex` method in the `Generator` class, unless I create a `GUI` object within my `Generator` class and then call the method to get the `width`. But I am pretty sure thats not what you're supposed to do.

It would make more sense if all these variables that the `Complex` method wants was instead put in the constructor. Then it would make sense to me, but they are not.

```
private Complex[][] mesh(double minRe, double maxRe, double minIm,
     double maxIm, int width, int height){


        Complex[][] complex = new Complex[height][width];
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                complex[i][j] = new Complex (i, j);
            }
        }
        return complex;

    }
```

tldr: How do I get numbers from another class into this private method?

Answer (score 0):

You have a confusion of terms. Those are not *variables*. Those are *parameters*.

That's not a private class, it's a private *method*.

If `GUI` is an actual class, and has `height` and `width` as member *fields*, then it might be good to put this `mesh` method inside the same class. It can then use the same fields instead of having them passed as parameters.

This would be especially true if `mesh` is only ever called from `GUI`.

```
public class GUI {
    private int _width;
    private int _height;

    public GUI(int width, int height) {
        _width = width; _height = height;
    }

    private double Complex[][] mesh(double minRe, double maxRe, double minIm,
     double maxIm){
        // now you can use _width and _height
    }
}
```

---

If you can't change the GUI class, then there's not much you can do. Does the GUI class have width and height properties? Do you even *have* an instance of the GUI class?

Comment: We arent allowed to change GUI, thats a done class. All I have is the specification for the Generator class (which iam gonna write)which are:

/** Paints a picture in the window gui */
public void render(MandelbrotGUI gui);
/** Creates a matris where every element is a complex number with the correct coordinates.*/
private Complex[][] mesh(double minRe, double maxRe,
double minIm, double maxIm,
int width, int height);